# console message not showing

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm currently using jQuery JSONP to load a csv file as a data source for graphing.
Here is my code:

```
var query= "http://abc.123.com/somefile.csv"
$.ajax({
     url:query,
     dataType:'jsonp'
}).done(function(msg){
     console.log("done");
     for (vari=0; i<5; i++){
          drwaChart(i);
     }
});
```

Somehow, the console doesn't show the "done" with the above code, but will show the "done" with:

```
var query= "http://abc.123.com/somefile.csv"
$.ajax({
    url:query,
    dataType:'jsonp'
}).done(console.log("done"));
```

Could anyone provide some information on this issue? Cause i'm not even sure whether the data has been loaded or not at this point...

Thanks!

(fixed that ' " typo.. I mistyped when I copy my code here..)

Comment: Did you notice the colors in your code, that's an error! Wrong quotes !

Comment: The second piece of code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: The second code will output `done` in the console right away, regardless of wether the ajax call was completed, successful, or anything else for that matter, as it just calls the `log()` function right away.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start the data type with a `'` and close it with a `"` which is causing `console.log()` to be interpreted as a `string`. Simple mistake, easy fix :)

**Correct Code:**

```
var query= "http://abc.123.com/somefile.csv"
$.ajax({
     url:query,
     dataType:'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){ 
     console.log("done");
     for (vari=0; i<5; i++){
          drwaChart(i);
     }
});
```

Comment: @user1948847 So what is holding you back from closing this thread? Is there still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first code when you say

```
.done(function(msg){console.log("done");....}
```

the console.log command is inside a wrapper function and is executed only if the results are received successfully, otherwise it does not run the console.log and since you have mistakenly use 'json" rather than 'json', (use single quote) your call does not succeed (You may also have some mistakes in server side in sending the results back to the jquery). Hence, your .done is not executed.

However, in the second code it does not check successful condition because probably you have no wrapper function. So, it runs the console.log. Check the second code with the wrapper function and see what is the results.